# Android fab icon Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable'

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library, floating-action-button

In Android when i run application it fires this error:

```
Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

The error fires when i uncomment those lines:

```
 fabAddLocation = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_add_location);

        fabAddLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ...
            }
        });
```

I think it may be compatibility issue. I using the below support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
```

And thise config in module build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage.myproj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

The activity extends AppCompatActivity

XML Layout of the Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="....MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_location"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the xml layout file in which this fab is defined or created.

Comment: @AnuragSingh i updated the question with the XML

Comment: Could you just change android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_fab" to android:src="@drawable/some.png". Do let me know what happens.

Comment: Same thing i try to remove the src icon at all and the same error happen

Answer (score 0):

Try adding multiDexEnabled true in your build.gradle(Module: app) file defaultConfig section and rebuild projects.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you insert the mdpi hdpi xxdpi.. icons with android studio asset image tool..
this was my problem